# Moving Google Drive Files to Another Computer Without Redownloading All of the Contents

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm currently using Google Drive on my laptop. I'm getting a new laptop soon and want to use the same Google Drive account on this new laptop.

I know that I can install Google Drive and download all the files from the cloud, but I am concerned about my data usage since I'm living in India (my data gets capped at 20 GB every month).

I wanted to move all of the files in my current Google Drive folder manually to the new computer. Will Google Drive automatically recognize that the files are the same and link them, or will it download a new set from the cloud and mark them with (1) beside each file?

Is there any other solution that I am not considering that will allow me to move my files locally and not have to re-download / re-upload all of the existing files?

Comment: How did you resolve this?

Comment: From my recent experience, this is no longer a problem

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been 3 years, but for the sake of eternal internet knowledge, Michael Richardson's article might help you and maybe others that stumble here:

http://rainabba.blogspot.co.il/2013/07/how-to-really-move-your-google-drive.html
(I'm sorry, Michael, but StackOverflow won't allow me to paste the shortened URL)

The old guide said you should disconnect your account, move the files to the new folder, then edit the files in `%appdata%\Local\Google\Drive\` using a Hex editor and change the path there to the new path.
In an update from April 2017, Michael said that Google has updated the client so that it can now recognize existing folders. So now you should just point the Drive client to the new folder. I couldn't figure out if it needs to be done before or after you disconnect from the account, but if anyone can try this (I can't do it right now) then please share your conclusions.

Good luck!

Comment: Could you edit your answer to include the steps mentioned in the article? You can definitely keep the link for attribution, but in the event that the link becomes invalid in the future, it's always good to put all relevant information in the answer itself.